# Is there a tool/way to show what rewards (badges etc.) were bestowed as a result of a particular question?

Tags: support, badges

I've been reading up on some of the older questions just out of interest and found myself wondering what was awarded as a result of them.

For example, it's clear what reputation points were awarded for asker/answerers, etc., but is there a method by which it's possible to view any badges that were gained from a particular answer?

I figured out that you can go to a user's page, click on a badge and see what answer/question it was awarded for, but I'd have liked to be able to see somewhere on a question that user X gained badges Y & Z for their efforts.

Is this possible, and I just don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no such tool.

However, there are certain badges that will be awarded for the posts. You can know more about them via reading [Badges](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

Here you can see, that badges like Nice Question, Good Question, and Great question are awarded when a question reaches the score of 10, 25 and 100 respectively. So, if you see a question that has a score of 10, the poster would definitely have a Nice Question badge. That's true for most of those Questions and Answers badges.

There are also badges which you cannot know if are awarded from a question's page. You will have to go to user's profile to know more.